# Preserve blank lines in bash heredoc with command substitution

Tags: bash

How can I maintain (or otherwise control) trailing blank lines from a command inside a heredoc (in bash)? Blank lines that are subsequently followed by non-blank lines are preserved correctly.

Consider:

```
$ cat <<EOF
> $(echo -en "hi\n\n")
> EOF
hi
$ cat <<EOF
> $(echo -en "hi\n\nfoo\n")
> EOF
hi

foo
$
```

Where did the blank line after `hi` go, and how can I keep it?

Calling `echo` directly has the desired result:

```
$ echo -en "hi\n\n"
hi

$
```

From my investigation, this happens to command substitutions, but not variables... any ideas why?

```
$ x=$'hi\n'
$ cat <<EOF
> ${x}
> EOF
hi

$
```

Comment: I'm not answering "how can I?" (therefore just a comment). I think I know the answer to "why?". When you run e.g. `date +%Y`, you want the result printed with a newline, so your prompt or the output of the next command is not glued to `2022`. Or when you redirect the output to a file, you usually want the line in the file to be properly terminated. But when you capture it like `y=$(date +%Y)` or use directly (e.g. `echo "$(date +%Y) is the year."` or especially `mv foo "foo-$(date +%Y)-backup"`), you hardly ever want the newline. For this reason `$(…)` removes all trailing newlines. (cont'd)

Comment: (cont'd) I admit it might be better (more predictable) if it was "one trailing newline", not "all". Unfortunately the [POSIX standard](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18_06_03) says "one or more" and I don't think it's going to change. AFAIK [even `zsh` does not try to "fix" this](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/206584/108618).

Comment: Very interesting, I'd agree that "the last trailing newline" would feel more sensible(?), but alas - thanks for the POSIX link too!